# why does pytorch's utils.save_image() change the color of my image

Tags: python, pytorch, adversarial-attack

I am saving two images with pytorch's utils.save_image() function [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.utils.save_image.html#torchvision.utils.save_image). one is the real image and the other, the perturbed image (just a patch). However, the latter image lost its real appearance when saved with save_image().

```
# save source image
utils.save_image(data.data, "./%s/%d_%d_org.png" % ("log", batch_idx, labels),
                            normalize=True)
    
# save adv image
utils.save_image(noised_data.data, "./%s/%d_%d_adv.png" % ("log", batch_idx, target_class), normalize=True)
```

This is the saved clean image[image: clean image]

This is the saved perturbed image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to solve this by adding make_grid() to the save method and clipping the image to [0,1] without normalizing.

```
utils.save_image(utils.make_grid(torch.clip(noised_data.data, 0, 1)), "./%s/%d_%d_adv.png" % ("log", batch_idx, target_class))
```